# How to keep parts of single object easily selectable in 2.8?

Tags: modeling, vertex-groups, groups, collections

I have a humanoid character, and I want to be able to select and move it's parts (like the hand highlighted on the photo) easily - that is without having to select all their vertices/faces all the time:

[image]

I tried 2 approaches: make hand a separate object, and use parenting - this does not work, since the edge vertices will not be connected to other parts, and I would need to snap them to edge vertices of other parts every time I move any part, to keep the mesh seamless.

Second approach - use vertex groups - looks like it's just what I need, but the select feature is *not yet implemented*...

Have I missed something? How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Vertex groups are integral to many aspects of blender, it is definitely implemented!

Comment: Apparently there are placeholder in the outliner panel context menu for vertex group operators but as of 2.81 they still have not been implemented after the redesign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want vertex groups as you've mentioned.

So go into *Edit Mode*, then press <kbd>1</kbd> to make sure you are selecting vertices.

Go into plan view with <kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> so we're all setup.

Now click open the *Mesh Properties* Panel and expand *Vertex Groups* if not already visible.

Now the essential part. Click the **+** button to create a new vertext group.

Double click it to rename *Hand*

[image: Vertex Group Panel]

Then in *3D view* box select all the vertices of your hand and click **Assign**.

This *assigns* the selected vertices to the group.

Now if you deselect all vertices, you can select them again by clicking **Select**.

You should now have all vartices which were assigned to the group selected again.

Comment: The reason I said select from plan view is an arbitrary choice, but because you're model is sideways I chose the easiest option.  Note that the convention for modelling is X (left, right) Y (front, back) & Z(below, above).

Comment: Great! I've tried to do just that, but using the Scene tree - there, in the object folder you can see it's vertex groups just like in the properties window. Right clicking the group shows a context menu, with select/deselect options. _those_ are not implemented, and you are notified about it with a popup at the bottom.

Comment: Oh, wow ... I see!  Suprised that didn't get fixed in 2.81.  Guess I should try to fix that for 2.82.  The scene tree ( or outliner ) was redesigned for 2.8x series, so there are a lot of things that don't work from there, the way I have shown is the old school way and does work.